# Picture vs. Photo vs. Image - Naming models

Tags: naming

I'm writing a gallery and my goal is not just photos but all kinds of images are going to be in there.

Now comes the naming part, what do I name my model?
Photo gives the feeling that it's only for photos. Image is a well used word for any graphics but is originally used when creating an image **of** something, like a person or a house.

So what makes the most sense:

- Image
- Photo
- Picture

Comment: I flagged this post because I think it's going to solicit too much opinion and not enough facts. I don't think there is going to be a conclusive answer.

Comment: True, I thought as much too. However it is tagged as naming and that would get a fair amount of opinion anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image is a Digital Asset

Photo and picture are more traditional with cameras and paintings.